# Is there a way to get a nested value from a YAML file into a shellscript?

Tags: python, shell, yaml, sh

Aside from using yq, is there a way to get the nested variable within a YAML file into a shellscript?

Example: Consider the following yaml file

```
test.yaml
    main:
     item1: value1
     item2: value2
```

Is there a way to fetch the values item1 and item2 into shellscript variables?

Using grep,

```
item=$(grep -h "item1" test.yaml)
actual=${item#*:}
```

The above would give the value I need but is there also a better way to approach it?
This retrieved value would be used for other tasks within the shellscript
I do have the option of using python with the yaml library and then running the python script from within the shellscript but which would be the **optimal** way of doing it?
I would prefer if the solution doesn't involve installing any packages/dependencies but suggestions are welcome

Comment: Using `grep` for structured formats like XML, JSON, YAML, etc is never a good idea. I wonder why you dismiss `yq`. That would be, in my opinion, the "optimal" way.

Comment: It does not make sense to say that you don't want to install any packages. Your shell is (likely) a package, as is grep.

Comment: Generally, if you must make restrictions about what answer you'll accept, please explain the reasons behind those restrictions so that we can understand your requirements. Also note that terms like *optimal* are not well-defined in complex areas such as shell scripting and therefore it's unclear what you want to optimize for. Speed? Memory usage? Lines of code? Usually you won't get everything from one single solution.